# Which debugger should I use to flash: RTL8710AF wifi SDK by Keil or IAR IDE

Tags: programming

I just bought a Realtek wifi module RTL8710AF and also found its TCP/IP stack Using IAR Workbench but I am confused in choosing the right debugger and its connection to flash my application program.

Comment: "Which debugger should I use" is a shopping question, which is off-limits on the SE websites. EE.SE is about electronic design.

Answer (score 0):

Since the WiFi module contains an ARM Cortex M3 core, it can likely be programmed / debugged with almost any SWD adapter, if given compatible software.

The official evaluation board for it has an CMSIS-DAP SWD implementation.

When starting out you may want to look at the tool selections and flows used in official examples, or published writeups from 3rd party users; pioneering ways of doing things from scratch or with alternate tools is more of a project for those with previous experience interacting with ARM Cortex-M series cores via SWD.